# Ternary tree with ditstance 4

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Ternary tree is represented by T is tree that has three children except for root. in T3(tree with height 3) how many pair of vertices (u,v)  that have distance 4 from each other? (u,v) and (v,u) could be count as 1

[image]

attempt:
in left subtree $2,5,6,7$, eccentricity of 4 is $3*6=18 + 9=27$ for example $14-5-2-6-17 $

which then total for $\{2,5,6,7\},\{8,3,9,10\},\{11,4,12,13\}$ subtree is $27*3=81$
for subtree including root $\{2,3,4,1\}$ there will be $18+9=27$
so total will be $27*4=108$
is my reasoning right?

Comment: I was thinking that the "," and "." buttons on your keyboard were broken.

Comment: @Robo300 Thankyou for answering my question but there is other possibility too such as (14,4) $\{14-5-2-1-4\}$ have distance 4  and (3,40)  $\{3-1-4-13-40\}$ also ,but how can i count all possibility?

Comment: @Robo300 which mean i just have to total distance from vertex 2,3,4 = 18*3=54 and total = 54+108=162 (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subtrees with $2,3$ and $4$ as roots each contain  $\frac{9\times 6}{2}$ pairs; a total of $81$ pairs.

Now consider pairs of vertices in different subtrees.

Each of the $27$ vertices on the bottom row can be paired with $2$ of the vertices in $\{2,3,4\}$; a total of $54$ pairs.

Each of the $9$ vertices on the next to bottom row can be paired with $6$ of the other  vertices in this row; a total of $\frac{9\times 6}{2}=27$ pairs.

The total is confirmed as being $162$.

Comment: That’s right, in my earlier comments I missed the pairs within the subtrees